# Работа с socket.io в angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angular2

Приветствую, пишу на `angular 2` и не могу сообразить как организовать подключение к `соккетам` в отдельном сервисе, что бы потом работать с его методами в разных классах.

Проблема заключается в том, что при создании сервиса и импорте больше одного раза в проекте, `соккеты` подключаются столько раз, сколько было импортов по проекту.

Перелазил весь инет, есть только примеры подключения, которые не решают проблему мульти импорта по проекту.

**Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это, скорее всего, происходит потому что вы указываете сервис в блоке `providers` у каждого компонента отдельно. В этом случае для каждого компонента будет создан свой экземпляр сервиса. Попробуйте добавить свой сервис в секцию `providers` у главного компонента. 
Подробности: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198785/how-do-i-create-a-singleton-service-in-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

Для 2.0 Release соответственно зависимость для сервисов надо теперь прописывать единожды в NgModule:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-root-component-or-module