# angular2 передача данных между компонентами

Tags: angular2

Не получается передать данные посредством модели. Есть  базовая компонента *(UsersComponent)* ещё одна компонента *(DriversApplicationsComponent)* и модель *(SearchModel)*
*DriversApplicationsComponent* является дочерней компонентой *UsersComponent*

```
path: 'drivers_applications', component: UsersComponent,
children: [
   { path: 'application',  component: DriversApplicationsComponent },
              ...
   ]
```

*SearchModel* должен хранить данные, которые передаёт *UsersComponent*, а в *DriversApplicationsComponent* получать данные из этой модели.

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private user: User, private router:Router, private _translate: TranslateService, @Inject(SearchModel) private searchModel:any) {
       this.userInfo = this.user.getInfo();
   }

  searchResult(result) {

       this.searchModel.setResult(result); 
  }

}
```

*SearchModel*

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchModel {

    public searchEvent:EventEmitter;
    public result = {};

    constructor() {
        this.searchEvent = new EventEmitter();
    }

    setResult(data) {
       this.searchEvent.emit(data);
    }

    subscriber() {
       return this.searchEvent;
    }
}
```

*DriversApplicationsComponent*

```
export class DriversApplicationsComponent implements OnInit{



constructor(private user: User, private filterService: FilterService, private searchModel:SearchModel) {
    this.searchModel.subscriber()
                    .subscribe(
                      res => {
                          //должен быть результат поиска, но его нет
                      }
                   )

}

....
}
```

Получается, что конструктор модели отрабатывает 2 раза, тоесть 2 отдельных инстанса. Как передать данные посредством модели?

Comment: Не совсем понял из чего получается, что сервис `SearchModel` создается дважды но если так, проверьте не указываете ли вы его где-то еще в провайдерах кроме `app.module.ts`

Comment: Да, спасибо за подсказку. В этом и была проблема. Я почему то думал, что если добавлять в разных компонентах  сервис то это будет один и тотже инстанс, а получается его надо было 1 раз добавить и больше нигде не добавлять.

Comment: Похожая проблема была тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576198/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-socket-io-%d0%b2-angular-2 . Почему сервис создается дважды подробно описано тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198785/how-do-i-create-a-singleton-service-in-angular-2

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно

Answer (score 1):

В проекте должны быть специальные обьекты - сервисы, это классы отчечающие за подотовку данных для компонентов которые используются для отображения этих данных.

В конструкторе компонента отображения вы просто подписываетесь на сервис с данными.

вроде:

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService
```

в вашем случае вы не задействуете ваш сервис в рантайме, только при инициализации компонента, а нужно обратаывать события которые создаейт пользователь - например изменение текста в контроле поисковой строки.